# Highstock flag doesnt have vertical line on first load, but does on second

Tags: jquery, highcharts, gantt-chart

I'm having an issue using Highstock.
I've created a Gantt chart and on there I've created a function to add a flag for today.
See fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/YQ7G8/

```
    function chartTodayFlag(YVal) {
        return {
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            title: 'Today',
            type: 'flags',
            data: [{
                x: new Date()
            }],
            y: YVal,
            shape: 'squarepin',
            color: 'red'
        };
    }
```

I can't seem to repeat the issue here as it works every time in jsfiddle.
However, in my system the first time the graph loads, there is no vertical red line.

[image: Example]

On refreshing the page the vertical line exists.

Comment: Any errors from console? For me it looks like you have old version of Highcharts.

Comment: Pawel, thanks for the reply.
No errors what so ever.
The confusing thing is that its only on first loading the page.
Once you reload it works fine.
Also most of the time, providing you've been on the page before, it will work fine.

Comment: Also I have checked the version; Highstock JS v1.2.5 (2012-12-19).
Updating to latest does not fix this issue

Comment: Could you show your page? What cross my mind is something with cache.

Comment: Pawel, I can arrange for you to have a temporary login to have a look, though I cannot mention it here for obvious reasons.
What's the best way to get the login info to you?

Comment: Contact me direct on mail support for Highcharts.